# SQL to Generate Periodic Snapshots from Transactions Table

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

I'm trying to create a periodic snapshot view from a database's transaction table after the fact. The transaction table has the following fields:

- account_id (foreign key)
- event_id
- status_dt
- status_cd

Every time an account changes status in the application, a new row is added to the transaction table with the new status. I'd like to produce a view that shows the count of accounts by status on every date; it should have the following fields:

- snapshot_dt
- status_cd
- count_of_accounts

This will get the count for any given day, but not for all days:

```
SELECT status_cd, COUNT(account_id) AS count_of_accounts
FROM transactions
JOIN (
      SELECT account_id, MAX(event_id) AS event_id
      FROM transactions
      WHERE status_dt <= DATE '2014-12-05') latest
USING (account_id, event_id)
GROUP BY status_cd
```

Thank you!

Comment: What database are you using?  I would guess Oracle, but you should be explicit with the tags on the question.

Comment: Yeah Oracle. Thanks for the tip! I mostly find that it's not too hard to translate proprietary extensions from one SQL to another, but it'd be nice not to have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is going to be hard to explain.

On each date for each status, you should count up two values:

- The number of customers who start with that status.
- The number of customers who leave with that status.

The first value is easy.  It is just the aggregation of the transactions by the date and the status.

The second value is almost as easy.  You get the *previous* status code and count the number of times that that status code "leaves" on that date.

Then, the key is the cumulative sum of the first value minus the cumulative sum of the second value.

I freely admit that the following code is not tested (if you had a SQL Fiddle, I'd be happy to test it).  But this is what the resulting query looks like:

```
select status_dte, status_cd,
       (sum(inc_cnt) over (partition by status_cd order by status_dt) -
        sum(dec_cnt) over (partition by status_cd order by status_dt)
       ) as dateamount
from ((select t.status_dt, t.status_cd, count(*) as inc_cnt, 0 as dec_cnt
       from transactions t
       group by t.status_dt, t.status_cd 
      ) union all
      (select t.status_dt, prev_status_cd, 0, count(*)
       from (select t.*
                    lag(t.status_cd) over (partition by t.account_id order by status_dt) as prev_status_cd
             from transactions t
            ) t
       where prev_status_cd is null
       group by t.status_dt, prev_status_cd
      ) 
     ) t;
```

If you have dates where there is no change for one or more statuses *and* you want to include those in the output, then the above query would need to use `cross join` to first create the rows in the result set.  It is unclear if this is a requirement, so I'm leaving out that complication.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! There's a typo in your code (should be `prev_status_cd is **not** null`), but other than that it works great.

Comment: I would like snapshots for dates without status changes. Is there a more elegant way to do it than this:

`SELECT DISTINCT status_dte,
       status_cd,
       (SUM(inc_cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY status_cd ORDER BY status_dte) - SUM(dec_cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY status_cd ORDER BY status_dte)) AS dateamount
FROM ((
     SELECT status_dte, status_cd, 0 AS inc_cnt, 0 AS dec_cnt
     FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT status_cd
          FROM transactions)
     CROSS JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT status_dte
          FROM transactions))
UNION ALL (
...`