# How to generate point in time snapshot table from a transaction fact table?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

I have a transaction table that records the change in status (A,B,C,D) of a customer by closing the end date of the previous record and also opening a new record with the current system time and the end date for the new record will be set to a high open date.

| FactID | Cust_ID | Status | EffectiveDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM |
| 2 | 1 | B | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM |
| 3 | 1 | C | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM |
| 4 | 1 | A | 24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM |
| 5 | 1 | D | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 |

I'm trying to build a snapshot at a point in time table (end of the day reporting) based on the above transaction table.

| ReportDate | Cust_ID | EODStatus | A_SDate | A_EDate | B_SDate | B_EDate | C_SDate | C_EDate | D_SDate | D_EDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | A | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 21/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | B | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 22/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | B | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 23/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | B | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 24/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | D | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 |
| 25/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | D | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 |

I'm now stuck when I try to expand the transaction table before building the snapshot. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
WITH
    date_ranges
    AS
        (SELECT ROWNUM, TO_DATE ('21-05-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1.00001 reportdate
           FROM all_objects
          WHERE ROWNUM <= 6),
    transactions (factid, cust_id, status, effectivedate, enddate)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 1, 'A', TO_DATE ('20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), TO_DATE ('21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 1, 'B', TO_DATE ('21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 1, 'C', TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 1, 'A', TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 1, 'D', TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL),
    dataset
    AS
        (SELECT DISTINCT reportdate,
                         cust_id,
                         status     AS eodstatus,
                         effectivedate,
                         enddate
           FROM transactions CROSS JOIN date_ranges)
  SELECT reportdate,
         cust_id,
         eodstatus,
         effectivedate,
         enddate,
         CASE
             WHEN eodstatus = 'A' THEN MIN (effectivedate)
             ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         END             AS a_sdate,
         CASE WHEN eodstatus = 'A' THEN MAX (enddate) ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
         END             AS a_edate,
         CASE
             WHEN eodstatus = 'B' THEN MIN (effectivedate)
             ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         END             AS b_sdate,
         CASE WHEN eodstatus = 'B' THEN MAX (enddate) ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
         END             AS b_edate,
         CASE
             WHEN eodstatus = 'C' THEN MIN (effectivedate)
             ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         END             AS c_sdate,
         CASE WHEN eodstatus = 'C' THEN MAX (enddate) ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
         END             AS c_edate,
         CASE
             WHEN eodstatus = 'D' THEN MIN (effectivedate)
             ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         END             AS d_sdate,
         CASE WHEN eodstatus = 'D' THEN MAX (enddate) ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
          END             AS d_edate
    FROM dataset t
   WHERE reportdate BETWEEN effectivedate AND enddate
GROUP BY reportdate, cust_id, eodstatus, effectivedate, enddate
ORDER BY reportdate, cust_id, eodstatus;
```

| REPORTDATE | CUST_ID | EODSTATUS | EFFECTIVEDATE | ENDDATE | A_SDATE | A_EDATE | B_SDATE | B_EDATE | C_SDATE | C_EDATE | D_SDATE | D_EDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | "A" | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 21/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | "B" | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 22/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | "B" | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 23/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | "B" | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 |
| 24/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | "D" | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 |
| 25/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | "D" | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 |

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c50f8/7)

**PS:** I had a look at another [thread in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327374/sql-to-generate-periodic-snapshots-from-transactions-table) which had almost the same title but wasn't much helpful.

**Update 1:**

I am now able to get a daily status for all reporting dates, yet the start & end date calculations and carrying forward the values to the subsequent rows is still not happening (as I am yet to figure it out).

- Start date - MIN (effectivedate for a given status)
- End date -   MAX(Enddate for a given status)

**Update 2:**
The start date and end date calculated must not be greater than the reporting date. Refer to the SQL output which showcases the current issue

Comment: Instead of date `9000-12-31` you may use `NULL` Would be more consistent.

Comment: SQL Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c50f8/1

Comment: So, you say you are stuck when you try to expand the transaction table -- could you be more explicit to help me understand the specific issue -- what is the issue? :)

Comment: `NULL` may look better from theory @WernfriedDomscheit, but makes the query more complex (and possible *inconsistent*). Instead of `some_date >= EffectiveDate and some_date < EndDate` (to get the version at some timestamp) you have to use some additional  `NVL`or `OR` conditions. Often is the `EndDate` decreaed by the lowest precision (e.g. 1 second for DATE) to get even simpler predicate `some_date BETWEEN EffectiveDate and EndDate`. Did you encounter `NULL` in a practical project?

Comment: I have an application where `some_date` is used as partition key, there `NULL` is not possible. But even there I use `NULLIF(some_date, DATE '9000-12-31')` in order to write consistent queries.

Comment: There is much discussion in SO and elsewhere about whether to use NULL or a large date. From my perspective, having to use `NULLIF` makes the query non sargable and is therefore a performance time bomb. It also means sprinkling magic constants throughout every query.

Comment: We are digressing from the original question. NULL or an open high-end date doesn't matter. This is for some other time, perhaps :)

Comment: I think you'll need to respond to this comment _So, you say you are stuck when you try to expand the transaction table -- could you be more explicit to help me understand the specific issue -- what is the issue?_ to progress.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Updated the question

Comment: I guess if the client in is state A for multiple time periods in the past, you just want to pick the most recent one to be shown? That's the hardest part about pivoting from/to to columns - resolving gaps and islands

Comment: Basically MIN for start date and MAX for end date in the case of multiple statuses

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What is *"expanding the transaction table"* and "*building the snapshot"*? Do any of the [temporal validity](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/temporal-validity-12cr1) features help? It's a bit unfortunate that all of your date ranges overlap. Can that be changed?

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even notice the dates overlap. That's a problem.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Cannot change them. I am not able to limit the start and end date based on reporting date which is causing the issue.Report date 22nd gives me the A_Enddate as 24th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all my sincere thanks to all the people who tried to help me. I somehow managed to nail this near-impossible task with some convoluted logic (but it works).  I tried providing inline comments to explain the derivations. A special mention to @Wernfried Domscheit who has written the PIVOT logic and deleted the answer and it helped me to a great extent.

```
WITH
    date_ranges
-- Generate dates 
    AS
        (SELECT ROWNUM, TO_DATE ('21-05-2021', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1.00001 reportdate
           FROM all_objects
          WHERE ROWNUM <= 6),
-- Mock up source records
    transactions (factid, cust_id,status,effectivedate,enddate)
    AS
        (SELECT 1,1,'A',
                TO_DATE ('20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
                TO_DATE ('21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,1,'B',
                TO_DATE ('21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
                TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3,1,'C',
                TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
                TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4,1,'A',
                TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
                TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5,1,'D',
                TO_DATE ('24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
                TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL),
    dataset
-- Apply cross join to get report date into transactions
-- Could've been much better; time crunched
    AS
        (SELECT DISTINCT reportdate,cust_id,status     AS eodstatus,effectivedate,enddate
           FROM transactions CROSS JOIN date_ranges),
    dataset1
-- Ignore start and end dates if they are older than the reporting date
    AS
        (  SELECT reportdate,
                  cust_id,
                  eodstatus,
                  CASE
                      WHEN reportdate > effectivedate THEN effectivedate
                      ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                  END    AS effectivedate,
                  CASE
                      WHEN reportdate > enddate THEN enddate
                      ELSE TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                  END    AS enddate
             FROM dataset
            WHERE reportdate > effectivedate),
    dataset2
-- Grab the min of start and max of end for all reporting days
    AS
        (  SELECT reportdate,
                  cust_id,
                  eodstatus,
                  eodstatus               AS status,
                  MIN (effectivedate)     effectivedate,
                  MAX (enddate)           enddate
             FROM dataset1
         GROUP BY reportdate, cust_id, eodstatus),
    dataset_new
-- Apply PIVOT to capture the start and end date per known statues and replacing NULLs with high open end dates
    AS
        (  SELECT reportdate,
                  cust_id,
                  eodstatus,
                  COALESCE ('A','B','C','D')                           AS status,
                  NVL (a_sdate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    a_sdate,
                  NVL (a_edate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    a_edate,
                  NVL (b_sdate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    b_sdate,
                  NVL (b_edate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    b_edate,
                  NVL (c_sdate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    c_sdate,
                  NVL (c_edate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    c_edate,
                  NVL (d_sdate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    d_sdate,
                  NVL (d_edate, TO_DATE ('31/12/9000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))    d_edate
             FROM dataset2
                  PIVOT (MIN (effectivedate) AS "SDATE", MAX (enddate) AS "EDATE"
                        FOR status
                        IN ('A' AS "A", 'B' AS "B", 'C' AS "C", 'D' AS "D"))
         ORDER BY reportdate),
    date_manipulations
-- Merging multiple entries into one record a day
    AS
        (  SELECT reportdate,
                  cust_id,
                  MIN (a_sdate)     a_sdate,
                  MIN (a_edate)     a_edate,
                  MIN (b_sdate)     b_sdate,
                  MIN (b_edate)     b_edate,
                  MIN (c_sdate)     c_sdate,
                  MIN (c_edate)     c_edate,
                  MIN (d_sdate)     d_sdate,
                  MIN (d_edate)     d_edate
             FROM dataset_new
         GROUP BY reportdate, cust_id
         ORDER BY 1)
-- JOIN with transaction to report the original status 
SELECT a.*, b.status
  FROM date_manipulations a JOIN transactions b ON reportdate BETWEEN effectivedate AND enddate;
```

| REPORTDATE | CUST_ID | A_SDATE | A_EDATE | B_SDATE | B_EDATE | C_SDATE | C_EDATE | D_SDATE | D_EDATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | "A" |
| 21/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | "B" |
| 22/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | "B" |
| 23/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | 31/12/9000 | "B" |
| 24/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 | "D" |
| 25/05/2021 11:59:59 PM | 1 | 20/05/2021 8:52:29 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 21/05/2021 3:08:22 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 2:47:28 PM | 24/05/2021 4:15:45 PM | 24/05/2021 8:05:09 PM | 31/12/9000 | "D" |

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done Oracle for a while but you're after two components:

1. The current snapshot
2. A fixed historical snapshot

This generates a snapshot for a given hardcoded date. I don't have Oracle to check how variables work so you'll have to do the date variable part yourself.

Note:

- I'm assuming that a Cust_ID can only have one state at a time
- real world data is more complicated than this and there are always edge cases
- If there is no current state for the Cust, there will be no row
- Just noticed you have overlapping dates. That is a problem because a customer is in two states at the same time

You could join to a calendar table to run this for all dates but that can be very performance intensive, and ongoing you usually just want to generate every day to add to an existing table.

Below is the code copied from a fiddle

### Setup code

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (FactID int, Cust_ID int, Status varchar2(1), EffectiveDate DATE, EndDate DATE)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t (FactID, Cust_ID, Status, EffectiveDate, EndDate)
         VALUES (1, 1, 'A', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-20 08:52:29.000', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-21 03:08:22.000')
    INTO t (FactID, Cust_ID, Status, EffectiveDate, EndDate)
         VALUES (2, 1, 'B', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-21 03:08:22.000', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-24 02:47:28.000')
    INTO t (FactID, Cust_ID, Status, EffectiveDate, EndDate)
         VALUES (3, 1, 'C', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-24 02:47:28.000', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-24 04:15:45.000')
    INTO t (FactID, Cust_ID, Status, EffectiveDate, EndDate)
         VALUES (4, 1, 'A', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-24 04:15:45.000', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-24 08:05:09.000')
    INTO t (FactID, Cust_ID, Status, EffectiveDate, EndDate)
         VALUES (5, 1, 'D', TIMESTAMP'2021-05-24 08:05:09.000', TIMESTAMP'9000-12-31 00:00:00.000')         

SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

### Query

```
SELECT
T.Cust_ID, DATE '2021-05-25' ReportDate, T.Status, T.EffectiveDate,T.EndDate,
H.A_SDATE, H.A_EDATE, H.B_SDATE, H.B_EDATE, H.C_SDATE, H.C_EDATE
FROM
(
    -- Todays snapshot
    SELECT Cust_ID,Status, EffectiveDate,EndDate
    FROM t 
    WHERE DATE '2021-05-25' BETWEEN EffectiveDate AND EndDate 
) T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
-- Static capture of all states
    SELECT Cust_ID, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'A' THEN EffectiveDate ELSE NULL END) A_SDATE, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'A' THEN LEAST(DATE '2021-07-10',EndDate) ELSE NULL END) A_EDATE,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'B' THEN EffectiveDate ELSE NULL END) B_SDATE, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'B' THEN LEAST(DATE '2021-05-25',EndDate) ELSE NULL END) B_EDATE,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'C' THEN EffectiveDate ELSE NULL END) C_SDATE, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'C' THEN LEAST(DATE '2021-05-25',EndDate) ELSE NULL END) C_EDATE

    FROM t 
    -- Exclude state changes after the process date
    WHERE EffectiveDate < DATE '2021-05-25'
    GROUP BY Cust_ID
) H
ON T.Cust_ID = H.Cust_ID
```

Comment: The MIN & MAX should consider the values that are only < reportdate else it shows future values

Comment: I'll update the WHERE in the H subtable. Do you want the MAX value to show the report date when it actually after the report date?

Comment: The Report date time is to provide a snapshot at a point in time. So, MAX value should not be greater than report date unless its open ended high date

Comment: Ok yep I’ve edited that into the query using LEAST

Comment: If you expand this to all statuses, this will ignore the status C for the given example and still provide enddate which is greater than the reportdate

Comment: I updated the answer to include C and use a date of '2021-05-25' (any date prior to this would correctly ignore C). I don't have Oracle to test what I've posted, I mainly wanted to give you some ideas, but I see that I am slowly converging on your original query anyway.

Comment: +1 for the pointers. If you want you can use the SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c50f8/7 to test this out. Still the end date which is greater than the report date issue persists

Comment: Fiddle is great. However your dates are strings not dates so that's one problem

Comment: This fiddle uses dates. Please take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/072e2/24

Comment: If you run it for 22nd then it shows A_Enddate as 24th which is incorrect considering its a snapshot

Comment: I updated the fiddle for `2021-05-22` and A_EDATE is `2021-05-21T03:08:22Z`. I can't work out how to use parameters in Oracle / Fiddle. It reminds me how much I loathe Oracle. You can owrk out the parameter but yourself. I changed every date